# Query analyser to find source code location

Tags: php, mysql, debugging, stack, sourceanalyser

Im having trouble debugging/finding the source of a query. Is there a free/open source query analyser software which can connect with PHP to find the source location of a query.

(like source location feature described here: 
http://mysqlblog.fivefarmers.com/2013/06/03/finding-the-source-of-problematic-queries/)

Comment: any file grep tool?

Comment: Iv tried that but the query im looking for is generated using an eav model system. Ive tried loging all queries but no luck, the query only shows up on "show processlist".  I have a feeling it is from a function in the PDO class like rowCount but cant find where.